# Filtering index using has_many through relationships

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Both `Cities` and `Positions` are associated to `Jobs` through a has_many :through relationship.

On the `Jobs#Index` page, I have a form, which when submitted allows a user to filter jobs based on a combination of city and positions.

I got this to work, but know the code can be a lot better.

This is my `Jobs#Index` controller:

```
  def index 
    @cities = City.all
    @positions = Position.all

    @city = City.find(params[:city_id]) if params[:city_id] && params[:city_id] != "0"
    @position = Position.find(params[:position_id]) if (params[:position_id] && params[:position_id] != "0")

    @jobs = Job.all
    @jobs = @jobs.includes(:cities).where(cities: { id: @city }) if @city
    @jobs = @jobs.includes(:positions).where(positions: { id: @position }) if @position
    @jobs = @jobs.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)

  end
```

This is my `Jobs#Index` View:

```
- provide(:title, 'All Jobs')

.thinstripe_career
  .darken
    .container
      .row
        .span10.offset1
          .jobs_header
            .row
              .span7
                h2 All #{@city.name if @city} #{@position.name if @position} Jobs
              .span3
                == link_to "Sign up for Job Alerts!", "#", :class => "button"

- if current_user && current_user.admin? 
  == render 'shared/dashboard_header' 

.container
  .row
    .span10.offset1
      .job_search
        == form_tag jobs_path, :method => 'get', :id => "jobs_filter" do
          h2 I'd like jobs in
          .filter_sect
            == select_tag :city_id, content_tag(:option,'all cities...', :value=>"0") + options_from_collection_for_select(@cities, "id", "name", params[:city_id].to_i  ), :class => "basic" 
          .filter_sect
            == select_tag :position_id, content_tag(:option,'all roles...',:value=>"0") + options_from_collection_for_select(@positions, "id", "name", params[:position_id].to_i ), :class => "basic"           
          .filter_sect.filter_search
            == submit_tag "Search", :class => "button search_button button_black", :name => nil

      ul.jobs
        - if @jobs.any?
          == render @jobs
        - else
          li.non_founds
            h2 No jobs founds.
            p There are currently no jobs founds for these combinations. Sign up to requests

      == will_paginate
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `models/job.rb`, you can add scopes and use them chained on the controller:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Model
  scope :with_cities, ->(city) { includes(:cities).where(cities: { id: @city })  if city }
  scope :with_positions, ->(position) { includes(:positions).where(positions: { id: @position }) if position }

  # rest of the code ...
end
```

---

For `JobsController`, you can:

- Add a `before_filter` to load all the data, and if you need to use that data on other actions, you just need to append the name of that action too.
- Use [memoization](http://railscasts.com/episodes/1-caching-with-instance-variables?view=asciicast) to load the city and the position.

In `controllers/jobs_controller.rb`:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_data, only: [:index]

  def index
    @jobs = Job.with_cities(city).with_positions(position).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
  end

  # ...

  protected:

  def load_data
    @cities = City.all
    @positions = Position.all
  end

  def city
    @city ||= City.find(params[:city_id]) unless params[:city_id].empty?
  end

  def position
    @position ||= Position.find(params[:position_id]) unless params[:position_id].empty?
  end
```

---

On the view:

Use `try`, so instead of:

```
    - if current_user && current_user.admin? 
      == render 'shared/dashboard_header'
```

you could write:

```
    == render 'shared/dashboard_header' if current_user.try(:admin?)
```

Use `include_blank` and `prompt` options in `select_tag`. 
This not only simplifies the views, but also allows to use `params[city_id].empty?` on the controller.

```
select_tag :city_id, 
  options_from_collection_for_select(@cities, :id, :name, params[:city_id].to_i), 
    include_blank: true, prompt: "all cities...", class: "basic"
```

Finally, you could extract `ul.jobs` into a partial:

```
= render partial: 'jobs', locals: { jobs: @jobs }
```

Or even the `.job_search` div, especially if you'll be needing this somewhere else.